# Python Oracledb - Segmentation Fault Error

Tags: python, oracle, python-oracledb

When I use [oracledb](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) Python module in Thick mode, I get a `Segmentation fault` error on a huge database request with Oracle v11.2 client.

**Code:**

```
# main.py
import oracledb

oracledb.init_oracle(lib_dir='path/to/lib', config_dir='path/to/config')
connection = oracledb.connect(user='user', password='pwd', dsn=cs, sid=sid, encoding='utf-8')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cur.arraysize = 100

results = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE')
```

**Error:**

```bash
python main.py
Segmentation fault
```

What is the problem with this request?

Comment: What does MY_TABLE contain? Where do you get the segfault?

Comment: In my case, MYTABLE is Materialized View with a lot of columns and rows. I get the segfault after the line "results = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE')". I also have the error when I use SQL Alchemy + Pandas + dbOracle after "pandas.read_sql()" (pandas v1.1.5) even if I use chunks of size 1.  Setting "ORA_OCI_NO_OPTIMIZED_FETCH=1" fixed the issue 
with larger chunksize.

Comment: Ok! You can also try thin mode (by commenting out the call to init_oracle_client() as it doesn't have that particular bug. It doesn't have all of the same features but it does have all of the commonly used ones!

Comment: Oracledb client tell me that Thin mode is not compatible with Oracle DB v11.2.0, that's why I can only use Thick mode in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug in your Oracle Client version at the C level.

To correct it, try to set the `ORA_OCI_NO_OPTIMIZED_FETCH` environnement variable to `1` in order to disable fetch Oracle compression - which can make your code failed- before running your Python code:

```bash
export ORA_OCI_NO_OPTIMIZED_FETCH=1
python main.py
```

You can also try to update your Oracle client because this bug is probably fix in a more recent version or patch.

Comment: Yes the particular problem that ORA_OCI_NO_OPTIMIZED_FETCH resolves was fixed in 21c Oracle client libraries, and I think backported to a later 19c release (but I don't have that info with me).